# Upload large files to SharePoint 2010 using COM from web service

Tags: 2010, web-services, file-upload, com

I want to upload large files to SharePoint 2010 from web service using client object model.

Below is the code, which i am using to upload file to sharepoint.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)))
{
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, relativeurl, stream, true);
}
```

Problem is, it is working fine for small files only. but when i am uploading file with 120 MB, then it is throwing Operation TimeOut error. Then i set time out to 20 minutes using

```
spcontext.RequestTimeout = 1200000;
```

But still it is not working. Then i found that i need to increase file upload size limit on web application level.

So i set it to 200 MB, which is shown below:

[image]

But still it didn't work.

Then i found below site reference http://thuansoldier.net/?p=4328, which says that we need to allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes.

So i ran below commands on my SharePoint server also

```
$a = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$a.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 200000000
$a.Update()
```

But no luck.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Below is the my webservice code:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string UploadFilesToSharePoint()
    {
        try
        {
            string file = @"C:\TEST\Professional_Microsoft_SQL_Server_2012_Analysis_Services_with_MDX.pdf";
            UploadDocumentRPC("http://domain:port/sites/test/", "Docs", file);

            return "Successfully Uploaded.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

 public static void UploadDocumentRPC(string siteUrl, string libraryName, string filePath)
    {
        string method = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("put document:14.0.2.5420");
        string serviceName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(siteUrl);
        string document = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(libraryName + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        string metaInfo = string.Empty;
        string putOption = "overwrite";
        string keepCheckedOutOption = "false";
        string putComment = string.Empty;
        string result = string.Empty;

        string fpRPCCallStr = "method={0}&service_name={1}&document=[document_name={2};meta_info=[{3}]]&put_option={4}&comment={5}&keep_checked_out={6}";
        fpRPCCallStr = String.Format(fpRPCCallStr, method, serviceName, document, metaInfo, putOption, putComment, keepCheckedOutOption);

        byte[] fpRPCCall = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fpRPCCallStr + "\n");
        byte[] postData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        byte[] data;

        if (postData != null && postData.Length > 0)
        {
            data = new byte[fpRPCCall.Length + postData.Length];
            fpRPCCall.CopyTo(data, 0);
            postData.CopyTo(data, fpRPCCall.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            data = new byte[fpRPCCall.Length];
            fpRPCCall.CopyTo(data, 0);
        }

        HttpWebRequest wReq = WebRequest.Create(siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll") as HttpWebRequest;

        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, Domain);

        wReq.Credentials = credentials;
        wReq.Method = "POST";
        wReq.Timeout = 1000000;
        wReq.ContentType = "application/x-vermeer-urlencoded";
        wReq.Headers.Add("X-Vermeer-Content-Type", "application/x-vermeer-urlencoded");
        wReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = wReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            int chunkSize = 2097152;
            int tailSize;
            int chunkNum = Math.DivRem(data.Length, chunkSize, out tailSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < chunkNum; i++)
            {
                requestStream.Write(data, chunkSize * i, chunkSize);
            }

            if (tailSize > 0)
                requestStream.Write(data, chunkSize * chunkNum, tailSize);

        }

        WebResponse wresp = wReq.GetResponse();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(wresp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you try uploading using RPC? Refer this article: [link](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2014/07/uploading-large-documents-into.html). Steve has mentioned how to do this using RPC.

Comment: Is it supported for SharePoint onPremise?

Comment: Yes it is supported. Just remove the part where he has used `SharePointOnlineCredentials`.

Comment: Let me try, will let you know the result

Comment: Again same Time out error. Do i need to update anything in webservice?

Comment: It is working fine from console application, but not from web service

Comment: What type of web service is it - SOAP / Rest? How are you calling it? Can you elaborate more on that? Maybe post some code?

Comment: It is the SOAP webservice.

Comment: Please check my webservice code above, i have updated my question

Comment: Try setting the timeout of the webservice in web.config as `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="<<milliseconds>>" />`

Comment: Tried this also, but didn't work for me

Comment: Oh OK. Can you check this and see if the methods listed here work for you? [link](http://www.dofactory.com/topic/1215/how-to-overcome-web-service-timeout.aspx)

Comment: Are you talking about obj.Timeout = -1 ?

Comment: Yes. You may try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25958/discussion-between-uberz91-and-user5590).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upload using this code?

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("URL of the site collection");

Web oWeb = context.Web;
FileCreationInformation oFile = new FileCreationInformation();
oFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Work\Files\17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration.pptx");
oFile.Url = "File_To_Be_Uploaded_to_SP.mp4";
List docs = oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File File2BeUploaded = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(oFile);
context.Load(File2BeUploaded);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```